# DRBD write over boundaries of zvol?

Tags: nfs, zfs

Running two 14.04 LTS servers with drbd and heartbeat using zfs under drdb. Created a zvol with 1.5TB and xfs to format the zvol then nfs shared out to clients.  For unknown reason 1.94TB was being used qwhen running zfs list.  How is that possible?  The zpool size is 1.94 TB but the zvol which is being used for /dev/drbd0 is only 1.5TB.  Of course then drbd0 will have IO errors and when diskless. Has anyone seen this before?  Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this is related to https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/2383